# Python : JSon Output to a file

Tags: python, json

I have as an output from my Python script a JSon format and I want to write the JSon into a file.

I use

```
df_json.to_json(orient='records') 

with open('JSONData.json', 'w') as f:
     json.dump(df_json, f)
```

I have the following error:

```
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

[1746 rows x 2 columns] is not JSON serializable
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

My JSon output is as follows :

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "results": [
      1,
      2,
      3

    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 558599,
    "results": [
      4,
      5,
      6
    ]
  }
]
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're calling `df_json.to_json(orient='records')` but you don't use the results. Object is not going to mutate itself into a jsonisable object.

Serializing the original object obviously doesn't work (or there wouldn't be a `to_json` method on it)

Since the string is already `json`, you don't even need the `json` module (or `json` would try to serialize the *string* again, which is not what you want): just do:

```
f.write(df_json.to_json(orient='records'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have used this but I get some strange output with a slash ( \ ) before every  double quotes  ( " )

Comment: The output in my file is `"[
  {
    \"id\": 1,
    \"results\": [
      1,
      2,
      3

    ]
  } ]  "`

Comment: sorry, I was mistaken earlier. It's simpler than that. Edited my answer...

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was searching for ;)